# Implementar SplashScreen estilo WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy creando una aplicacion y quiero que al ejecutarse en dependencia del tema puesto por el SO la imagen del **SplashScreen** sea de fondo **claro** o **oscuro**. Tengo diseñada

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    switch (currentNightMode) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
            setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenWhite);
            break;
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
            setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenBlack);
            break;
    }

    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Alguna sugerencia de como pueda proceder?

Archivo splashwhite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_splash_screen_foreground"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Archivo styles

```
<style name="SplashScreenWhite" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashwhite</item>
</style>
```

> **Nota**: En android inferior a 7 me da este error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splashwhite.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700a8 estando el archivo presente. Que puede ser eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontre la respuesta a mi pregunta... Hay que crear una clase auxiliar que es la que nos va a ayudar a resolver todo...

```
public class InitApplication extends Application {
    public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
    private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

    private static InitApplication singleton = null;

    public static InitApplication getInstance() {

        if(singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new InitApplication();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        this.isNightModeEnabled = mPrefs.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, false);
    }

    public boolean isNightModeEnabled() {
        return isNightModeEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsNightModeEnabled(boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
        this.isNightModeEnabled = isNightModeEnabled;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Usando esa clase ahora puedo llamar a SplashScreen

```
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (InitApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled()) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenBlack);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenWhite);
        }


            wait3Seconds();
        }
    }
```

[fuente de consulta](https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode)

Comment: Añadir el ejemplo ayudaría a elevar la calidad de tu aporte, ya que responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, ya solo al último dejas el enlace para darle créditos al autor de la publicación

Comment: ahora lo edito gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que se usa `SystemClock.sleep()` y esto bloquea la ejecución del `thread` principal, imagino que en este caso nunca llegas a ver el `SplashScreen` y pasa directo al `LoginActivity`. Lo que debes que hacer es: Crear un *Runnable* con el código para pasar de *Activity* y ejecutarlo con un *Handler*.

Código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Desconozco cuál es la versión correcta, puedes intentar con O, O_MR1 y P
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
     configTheme();//Si la version es menor a P(api lvl 28, android 9) no se ejecutara esto
  }
  esperarTresSegundos();
}   private void esperarTresSegundos(){
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }, 30000);
}
private void configTheme(){
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
  int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
  switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
      // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
      setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenWhite);
      break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
      // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
      setTheme(R.style.SplashScreenBlack);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que cuando aplico los temas no lo coge me entiendes... A pesar de detectar el modo oscuro o no no me muestra ni una imagen ni la otra por eso publique la pregunta con algo que supuestamente creía que estaba bien si aún puedes ayudarme

Comment: Alex tal como lo publicaste el problema era el sleep() porque nunca se va a ejecutar el setTheme, en realidad se ejecutara justo al mismo instante que se ejecuta el pasar al otro activity asi que nunca verias diferencia.

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente tu solucion pero ahora para android menores que 7 me da error a la hora de buscar el recurso que puedo hacer puedes editar la respuesta?

Comment: @AlexRivas ahi modifique la respuesta. Cuando tengas problemas de version siempre podes usar if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.<codigo de version>) para chequear la version antes de ejecutar algo que apis mas viejas no soportan.

Comment: Ahora el único problema es que me sigue dando problema no encuentra el archivo xml que menciono arriba voy a modificar la respuesta para poner esos archivos y me puedas seguir ayudando

Comment: muchas gracias por toda la ayuda